# @RequestHeader behaviour not as expected; working without required User-Agent

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, spring-restcontroller

I have a project set up using Spring Boot with Kotlin to make REST APIs.

I'm trying to use the `@RequestHeader` to recognize the `User-Agent`. The said header is `required=true` -

```
@PostMapping("details", produces = ["application/json"])
    fun addInfo(@RequestHeader(name = "User-Agent", required = true) userAgent: String,
                   @Valid @RequestBody podEntity: PodEntity): ResponseEntity<String> {
        pod.addPod(podcastEntity)
        return ResponseEntity<String>("{ \"status\":\"Added\" }", HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }
```

Problems -

1. However, even if I'm not sending the `User-Agent` header, the API is working and adding data. But, if I change the header to any other non default names, like, `user` or `request-source`, the `required=true` requirement is enforced to and the API does not work. Does it mean that default headers cannot be made mandatory using the `required` tag?
2. The other problem is that in the case of custom header, when the required header is missing for the request, the API fails by giving 400 error code but does not throw any exception. I was expecting `HttpClientErrorException` for my junit test case but on checking the console, I see no exception. Adding `@Throws` is also not helping. How do enable my function to throw an exception when the required header is missing?

Unit test -

@Test
fun test_getAll_fail_missingHeaders() {

```
    val url = getRootUrl() + "/details/all"
    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    val request = HttpEntity(pod, headers)

    try {
        restTemplate!!.postForEntity(url, request, String::class.java)
        fail()
    } catch (ex: HttpClientErrorException) {
        assertEquals(400, ex.rawStatusCode);
        assertEquals(true, ex.responseBodyAsString.contains("Missing request header"))
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't have to set required=true. This is default. But the problem is that the user agent is never null but blank or has any value that the HTTP Client is sending. 2) how does your unit test look like

Comment: 1. I see. That makes sense. 2. Updated the question the with the unit test code.

Comment: 2) postForEntity will never rais an exception

Comment: But this tutorial - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-junit-resttemplate/ does exactly that. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Oh you are right. So have you checked what is different in your example than in the turoial?

Comment: So I was accessing the wrong API in the test. However, even after fixing that there is no exception. Just 400 error.

Comment: can you provide your code on Github?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. It is a private repo.

Comment: Can you creat a mimal example to show the problem?